# How to get ID from symfony Form Field to fill out rest of form

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I would appreciate any kind of help for this problem I'm having.

I have 2 Symfony Forms :

- One for the search part (Serial Number)
- Another form that will be filled out if the Serial Number exists.

I need to get dynamicly the value of the ID.

Here is a snippet of my code :

```
{% for ClientInfo in getInstallationClientBySerialNumber %}
<tr id="ClientInfo_{{ installClientInfo.idRma }}">
    <td><a href="" id="client_sn">{{ ClientInfo.numeroSerie }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

The loop works but I'm struggling with the JQuery part to get the ID. I've tried :

```
$("#client_sn").click(function(){
    var elmId = $("#ClientInfo_id").attr("id");
    alert(elmId);
});
```

Any help would be very kind.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTML ID's have to be unique on a page.  You're looping over multiple elements, giving them all the same ID "client_sn"

What you can do with Twig in a for loop is access `loop.index` as a counter
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

```
{% for ClientInfo in getInstallationClientBySerialNumber %}
<tr id="ClientInfo_{{ installClientInfo.idRma }}">
    <td><a href="" id="client_sn_{{loop.index}}">{{ ClientInfo.numeroSerie }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

In the jQuery you can then use a pattern to match all elements with an ID starting `client_sn`:

```
$("a[id^='client_sn']").click(function(){
    var elmId = $("#ClientInfo_id").attr("id");
    alert(elmId);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Or use some other selector to identify the links.

Alternatively instead of `{{loop.counter}}` you could reuse the `installClientInfo.idRma` ID you're also using:

```
{% for ClientInfo in getInstallationClientBySerialNumber %}
<tr id="ClientInfo_{{ installClientInfo.idRma }}">
    <td><a href="" id="client_sn_{{ installClientInfo.idRma }}">{{ ClientInfo.numeroSerie }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank You very much my friend !